# Get the domain name outside a Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How can I get the domain name of my Spring app outside a `Controller`?

I want to create a link to a `Controller` in a `@Scheduled` method, but here I don't have a `Request` object to get the domain name.

Comment: A scheduler runs outside the scope of a request right? You can either hold the `Request`' object when the call to initiate the scheduled task is made.

I am trying to understand, why would you need to call a controller from a scheduled task. You can just directly call the service that the controller refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do no think that you can get it in a @Scheduled method. This would be part of your configuration. 
ie you can set a value in the resources->xxxxx.properties file

```
domain = mydomain
```

and then in your service class you can get it like this

```
@Value("${domain}")
private String domain;
```

Hope this helps